# Why is the diagonal sum of my matrix still zero?

Tags: java, matrix, sum

In the generateMatrix I need to generate a square Matrix with values in range of `low` to `high`(inclusive), and in the `SumMajorDiagnal` I'm not sure if I'm doing the Diagnal sum correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Matrix{
  public static void main(String args[]){      

    int[][] matrix= new int[4][4];  

    int row=0;
    int column=0;
    int n=0;
    int sum=0;

    matrix[row][column]= (int)(Math.random() *20)+1;
    matrix = generateMatrix(n,row, column );
    printMatrix (matrix);
    sumMajorDiagnal (matrix);
    System.out.println("Sum of the elements in the major diagnol is " +  sum);
  }

  //I just don't know how to work the generateMatrix method
  public static int[][] generateMatrix(int n, int low, int high){
    int[][] m= new int[4][4];   
    for (int row=0; row <m.length; row++){
      for (int column=0; column<m[row].length; column++){
      }
    }
    return m;
  }
  public static int sumMajorDiagnal (int[] [] m){
    int sum=0;
    for (int diag=0; diag<m.length; diag++){
      sum+=m[diag][diag];
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public static void printMatrix(int[][]m){
    for (int row=0; row <m.length; row++){
      for (int column=0; column<m[row].length; column++){
        System.out.print(m[row][column]+ " ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's compiling but printing:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

The sum of the elements in the major diagonal is 0 so I know there is something wrong with the generateMatrix method. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[][] generateMatrix(int n, int low, int high){
  int[][] m= new int[4][4];
  int value = low;
  for (int row=0; row <m.length; row++){
    for (int column=0; column<m[row].length; column++){
        m[row][column] = value;
        ++value;
        if (value > high)
           value = low;
    }
  }
  return m;
}
```

or:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
...
  m[row][column] = low + rnd.nextInt(high - low + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listing has two major problems and two minor ones. First, the line

> matrix[row][column]= (int)(Math.random() *20)+1;

doesn't make sense where you've got it. I assume you meant it to be inside the inner loop in generateMatrix. Second, you're not assigning sumMajorDiagonal's return value to anything, which is why sum is still zero at your System.out.println.

The minor problems are that the initialization of matrix is pointless since generateMatrix constructs a new one, and there are unused parameters in generateMatrix.